JMeter Summary & Aggregate Total Average Response time seems invalid while using Transaction Controllers

I’m running a test with two Transaction Controllers, each containing three endpoints. After a single iteration, the Aggregate and Summary reports in JMeter show the Total Average Response Time as 85ms.
It appears that JMeter is calculating the total average by combining each request’s average response time with the average response times of the Transaction Controllers themselves. Why does JMeter include the Transaction Controllers' averages again in the overall total calculation?
My expectation was that the total average response time would be calculated by taking the average of each Transaction Controller group—specifically, dividing the total average time of each group by the number of groups. Alternatively, I thought the total average response time could be calculated by dividing the combined average response time of each request by the total number of requests.
In this case, JMeter seems to be dividing the combined total average of requests and Transaction Controllers by 8 to get 85ms. Shouldn’t it be calculated as 342/6 or 687/8?
I’d appreciate any guidance on how JMeter calculates summary report averages and why it includes Transaction Controllers in the total average calculation.
If this is an issue, how can we fix the summary report calculations?
For my final execution report, I need to see each transaction controller stats (Overall page load time for each page) as well as each request times in the summary report. SO, enabling 'Generate Parent Sampler' is not an option for me.

I think this is by design, according to documentation:

The Transaction Controller generates an additional sample which measures the overall time taken to perform the nested test elements.

If you think that behaviour of listeners is not correct you can raise an issue in JMeter project
You can use HTML Reporting Dashboard for results analysis, it doesn't consider Transaction Controller's execution time while calculating average response time.
You can check out What is JMeter’s Transaction Controller? article to better understand how does Transaction Controller work.
Also you can check Calculator.java source code, it might help in identifying logic behind JMeter's metrics and KPI.
